# Add Java API to online server not localhost

Tags: java, json, api

I have just created a Hello World RESTful Java API with IntelliJ IDEA and Spring and I make several requests with `http://localhost:8080/function` and it works fine and return the JSON data well, but now I want to make request from my android app to get the same JSON data from another network. How to create global API or make my local API global or online?

Answer (score 1):

If it is working on your PC, your next step is to host it somewhere which is reachable from the outside world. If it is still in testing mode, probably what you need to do is port-forwarding from your router, so that your requests to your public IP get forwarded to your PC.

In the long term of course you need to host it somewhere, unless you want to leave your PC running. You can buy a cheap hosting to start with on something like Digital Ocean, or go for the more advanced cloud service providers like Google and AWS.

Answer (score 0):

in your router you have to redirect port 8080 to you network IP and allow port 8080 in your firewall

And use this IP address https://whatismyip.com.br/

Answer (score 0):

You can create your java application in a container and deploy it on one of the cloud providers (AWS, Azure, Google App Engine).